# How to get point of the inscribed circle at the point on the square in C# (Unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to get point of the inscribed circle at the point on the square in C# (Unity3d)?
I make minimap with circle mask. I want marker of south in border of map.
I can calc max coordiantes if minimap is square:

```
    Rect mapRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;
    point = Vector2.Max(point, mapRect.min);
    point = Vector2.Min(point, mapRect.max);`
```

Comment: Is the position of the marker fixed or is it rotation? If it is fixed, you could add half of the rect height or the radius of the circle from the center of the circle or you could add half of the rect width to the rect x and the height to the y. There are a couple ways.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I cannot understand the question.

Comment: Here's the doco for RectTransform, it's pretty clear http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html

Comment: Something like the link I think, but with a South marker instead of a North marker. In his case he has a rect and an inscribed circle that masks the rect. Important to know now is if the marker is fixed or if it should rotate when the map rotates. Link to image: http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/wowwiki/images/7/79/Minimap-4_1_0.png/revision/latest?cb=20110611053708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. If I understand your question correctly, you want to create an arrow of sorts that points to some specified point on the map. Kind of like the blue the arrow in this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wowace.com](http://www.wowace.com/media/images/56/83/Bloodhound2.jpg))</sub>

Well, I would start off by creating a "Player position" object at the center of the masked minimap. We'll use this as a simple reference for the minimap's center and a UI object for the player, like the blue and silver arrow in the picture. Next, using calculus we can determine the angle between the center of the minimap and the marker. In calculus, an angle angle is equal to arctan(y/x). Between two positions, it is equal to arctan[(first y - second y)/(first x - second x)]. In Unity we can use Mathf to perform these functions. Let's assume the variable 'marker' is the RectTransform of the marker, and 'playerMarker' is the RectTransform of the player's UI object on the minimal that we made earlier.

```
    float yDistance = marker.anchoredPosition.y-playerMarker.anchoredPosition.y;
    float xDistance = marker.anchoredPosition.x-playerMarker.anchoredPosition.x;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan(yDistance/xDistance);
```

Now that we have the correct angle, we can set an arrow to be the position and rotation of that angle. We can immediately set the rotation. Let's use 'arrow' as the RectTransform variable for our arrow.

```
    arrow.rotation = Vector3(angle * Mathf.Rad2Deg, 0, 0);
```

For the position, we have to use more calculus. We want the arrow to be a certain distance away from the playerMarker, but at a certain angle. The distance should be a little bit less than the radius of the minimap. Let's call this distance 'arrowDistance'. So to set the arrow position:

```
    arrow.anchoredPosition.x = playerMarker.anchoredPosition.x + arrowDistance * Mathf.Cos(angle);
    arrow.anchoredPosition.y = playerMarker.anchoredPosition.y + arrowDistance * Mathf.Sin(angle);
```

And that should be it. THIS IS NOT TESTED. So if anyone finds a mistake, please point it out. Hope this helps!

Comment: I want calc positions of marker - "N" in your picture (http://prntscr.com/aj8y4v - red border).

Comment: oh. Well, just create a new UI text object in the editor. Place it at the top of the circle and make the text say 'N'. That is much much simpler hahah

Comment: I want that my some gameobject in scnene (which be my south) tracked in minimap.